# using awk to modify field with condition

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

**INPUT**

```
New,9,1
Old,11,0
```

**OUTPUT**

```
New,09,1
Old,11,0
```

I would like to append to filed number 2 after first `,` in case if it's single digit so i would like to add `0` before the digit as the output shown.

I were able to achieve that using `awk` but i lost `,` as separator.

using the following command

```
awk -F ',' '{if(length($2)==1)$2="0"$2;print $0}' inputfile
```

Comment: a small change in  your awk command will do the needful
 `awk -F ',' 'BEGIN { OFS=","};{if(length($2)==1)$2="0"$2;print $0}'`  
Using OFS will ensure that the commas are printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN { OFS=","};{if(length($2)==1)$2="0"$2;print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed` it is doable as like this :

```
   sed -Ee    's/,([0-9]),/,0\1,/'   input
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below awk method to achieve the same

_linux_example ~]# `awk -F "," '{if(length($2)<=1)print $1",0"$2","$3;else print $0}' file.txt`

output:

```
 awk -F "," '{if(length($2)<=1)print $1",0"$2","$3;else print $0}' filename

New,09,1
Old,11,0
```